# How to track the click event of a dynamically added iframe by using jquery's iframeTracker plugin

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins

I can track the click event of my i frame by using iframeTracker which is a plugin of jquery.this is the way i used..,

```
           $('.fb-like').iframeTracker({
                blurCallback: function(){
                   console.log("liked page");
                   window.location.href = "like_update";
                }

            });
```

But i cant detect the click whrn i dynamically added this i frame.The click doesnt detect by this iframetracker.Any way to track the click of dynamically added iframe?please help me.

Answer (score 0):

When an iframe is dynamically added to the page, you will need to re-initialize the iframe tracker to 'find' the new iframe. When you detect the event that adds the new iframe, and when `document.readyState === "complete"`, re-run your `iframeTracker` function.

You could create a function `checkForIframes`, and run it when you detect the 'add iframe' event. For example, attach the `checkForIframes` to a button that adds an iframe.

```
// document must be in readyState 'complete' before checking for iframes - $(document).ready() is not good enough!
    var checkForIframes = function () {
      console.log('start checkForIframes');

      var docReadyCheck, isDocReady;

      docReadyCheck = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
          console.log('check for iframes, now that the document is complete');
          clearInterval(isDocReady);

          $('.fb-like').iframeTracker({
            blurCallback: function(){
               console.log("New iframe added");
               // ...
            }

        });
        }
      };

      isDocReady = setInterval(docReadyCheck, 1000); // check once a second to see if document is complete
    };
```

If the new iframe is in a dialog box, you can detect when a dialog box is opened and run the `checkForIframes` function.

```
// triggered when a dialog is opened, recheck for iframes
$("body").on("dialogopen", function () {
  console.log('Detected a dialogopen event');
    checkForIframes();
});
```

I have not used this iframeTracker plugin, so I am not sure if this code is quite right, but I have an idleTimeout plugin that works with dynamically added iframes. You can see a demo of how to detect dynamically added iframes here: http://jillelaine.github.io/jquery-idleTimeout/iframe-demo.html